# html background image change to css?

Tags: javascript, css, html

created one Existing project its non responsive web site.Now i need to change Responsive site. i need to change my logo image responsive site? i changed but its not working?'

```
   <td colspan="2"  style="background-image:url('site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg'); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center;" width="100%" height="100" align="right" >
```

this code my site logo image how to change this image to full responsive logo?

i have created class file in html like

```
  <td class="img1">
```

My css code:

```
  @media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 568px)
  {

    .img1{
         background-image:url('site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg');
         background-repeat:no-repeat; 
         background-position:center; 
         width:100%;
         Height:100;
      } 
}
```

its not working in responsive ? any mistake my code ?

Comment: In your css code you typed "ackground-repeat".
Are you sure that your image is in the right folder with the right name?

Comment: spell mistake my code correct typed but not working i have put here part of code logo image code and css

Comment: background-image:url('../site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg'); try this

Comment: I've never seen anyone making a responsive site using tables

Comment: james king  i  will change code table to  div tag

Comment: Height has capital H. Not sure it works. Also, no unit given to height. Also you can try background-size: cover propety

Answer (score 0):

.img1 class is assigned to `<td>` so background-size property should be added to make the image occupy 100% size of the width.

**CSS**

```
.img1 {
    background-image: url('site_conf/images/det_banner.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 100% ;
    width: 100%;
    Height: 100px;
}
```

> Note: As your existing code is in Table structure I am not 100% sure
>   that my solution will work. but you can give it a try. if you can create a fiddle then it will be
>   easy to guide you.

Comment: thats might be because of your `<td>`  `width`. check in developer tools.